# How to delete words within parentheses except when the first word inside the parentheses is 'test' in Perl?

Tags: perl

How do I delete all words contained within parentheses (including the parentheses) except when the first word inside the parentheses is 'test' using Perl?

For example:

```
don't delete = (test 1)
               (test 2)

delete word(s) plus parenthesis = (scsi)
delete word(s) plus parenthesis = (normal)
```

Here's what I tried so far:

```
   $_ =~ s/\([a-oA-Oq-zQ-z].*\)//g;
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking you want to delete words in parentheses, plus the parentheses themselves, unless the parenthetical material starts '`(test`'?  If the text is `(test)`, is that deleted or not?  If the text is `(test me)`, then it is not to be deleted; is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try.....

```
s/\((?!test).*?\)//g;
```

Comment: Just to clarify: `?!` is a negative lookahead assertion and `.*?` forces minimal (nongreedy) matching.